# best-possible inequalities for hypergeometric functions

Tags: cv.complex-variables, inequalities, special-functions, hypergeometric-functions

In what follows, let $n$ be a positive integer and $0<a<1/2$. I am interested in the Gauss hypergeometric functions, $_{2}F_{1}( -n, -n-a; 1-a; z)$. Notice that these are polynomials, if that is helpful.

It is known since Riemann that asymptotically we have
$$
\frac{1}{n} \log \left| _{2}F_{1}(-n,-n-a;1-a;z) \right| \rightarrow
\log \left| 1+\sqrt{z} \right|^{2},
$$
as $n \rightarrow \infty$ for fixed $a$ and $z$. Here I am using the principal value for the square root.

I am looking for inequalities that are as of the same form roughly as these asymptotics and in particular for $|z|=1$, if restricting the domain is easier. I.e., inequalities of the form
$$
c_{1}(n,a) \left| 1+\sqrt{z} \right|^{2n} \leq \left| _{2}F_{1}(-n,-n-a;1-a;z) \right| \leq c_{2}(n,a) \left| 1+\sqrt{z} \right|^{2n}.
$$

Using Pochhammer's integral and some simple inequalities, one can obtain a value for $c_{2}(n,a)$, but it does not appear to be the best possible value.

From some calculations, it appears that
$$
\left| _{2}F_{1}(-n,-n-a;1-a;z) \right| \left| 1+\sqrt{z} \right|^{-2n}
$$
achieves its maximum on the unit circle at $z=1$ if $n$ is odd and $z=-1$ if $n$ is even. The minimum for $|z|=1$ appears to occur near $z=-1$. For fixed $a$, the location of this minimum approaches $-1$ as $n \rightarrow +\infty$.

Proving the claim about the maximum and obtaining a lower bound too are what I am ideally looking for, but have been unable to do so myself or find any such result in the literature.

Is anyone on MO able to help?

Comment: What is $r$ in your equations ?

Comment: oops! It's supposed to be $n$. Corrected now. Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: At least for one example your last conjecture seems not to hold. For $a=1/4$ and $n=6$ the given function achieves its minimum near $z = e^{i \pi 0.848 }$.

Comment: @Johannes Trost was away and just noticed your comment. Thanks for that. I made a mistake (or two!) in outputting the extreme values in my program. I corrected that, matched your min value for $a=1/4$ and $n-6$ and updated my question. Thanks again!

Comment: Have you checked the whole region of $a$ values in your calculations? From my calculations it seems, that your claim is correct only for $0<a<\frac{1}{2}$. For $a=\frac{1}{2}$ the given function assumes its maximum value, 1, on the unit cycle, at both $z=1$ and $z=-1$. For $\frac{1}{2}<a<1$ the (absolute) maximum seems to be at $z=1$ ($z=-1$) for even (odd) $n$, i.e., the other way round.

Comment: @Johannes Trost yes, you are right. I meant to add that when I edited my question the other day.